# UIButton breaks after hiding and unhiding

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have some UIButtons created on the storyboard in my view. On pressing one, I hide them all, and have a bunch of new UIButtons, created programmatically, pop up (one of which is a "back" button).

When I hit a back button (which hides the new buttons, and reveals the original ones), they no longer work.
From what I can tell, it is not getting to the @IBAction at all. It is not registering the hit.

```
//Hide buttons originally
        for button in menuButtonArray {
            button.isHidden = true
            button.isEnabled = false
        }

//Reveal buttons when "back" button is hit
        for button in menuButtonArray {
             button.isHidden = false
             button.isEnabled = true
        }
```

I've tried using .isUserInteractionEnabled to no avail. I've tried deleting the programmatically created buttons (instead of just hiding them). I've tried hiding the stack that contains the buttons, instead of the buttons themselves.

I figured this should just hide and show the buttons, but somehow it is breaking them?

Further weirdness, it does not break all of the buttons. The top and bottom buttons in my stack work, but not the 6 in-between.

---

UPDATE

Below is how I create and add buttons to menuButtonArray.
I've checked if I do a print of each button before and after enabling and disabling them, the tag is added and removed, seemingly correctly. Also, they hide and unhide no problem. Thanks for the help!!

```
var menuButtonArray: [UIButton] = [UIButton]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    menuButtonArray += [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7]
}
```

Comment: I suspect if you're declaring buttons programmatically and hiding them, the reference count drops to zero and they're getting deallocated. Where is your declaration for the `menuButtonArray` and what is the scope of the array?

Comment: try to inspect the layers and see if other buttons are blocking the buttons that "doesn't work as expected".

Comment: You might need to show a bit more code -- like how do you add the buttons to `menuButtonArray` and what else are you doing with `menuButtonArray` that you didn't put in your original question.

Comment: @Adrian I've just added the code in an update :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Thanks for the help! I figured it out. 
@finalstatic I inspected the layers. When I created the buttons programmatically, I use a grid of UIStackView to arrange them. I assumed, if empty, they'd just pass through clicks to the layer under it. Apparently not though haha!
I fixed it by hiding the UIStackView also!